# How can I set up clang-format in emacs?

Tags: init-file, clang

When running `clang-format-buffer` or `clang-format-region` when a region has been been selected, no change is made to the formatting. However, in `*Messages*`, I see `(clang-format: success)`. Using `clang-format` in the terminal works fine, and the emacs package `clang-format` is configured to point towards the correct location where `clang-format` is installed.

These are the only lines I have in my init.el related to `clang-format` (I've also tried all variations of setting / not setting `clang-format-style` and `clang-format-style-option`):

```
;; Clang stuff
(require 'clang-format)
(setq clang-format-style "file")
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to generate a `.clang-format` file in your project's root, with the command `clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format`.

More info on [this page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had already completed this step but turns out I hadn't.

Answer (score 3):

You set `clang-format-style` to `"file"`. In that case, `clang-format.el` will first look for a `.clang-format` file. It it finds one, it will use it. Otherwise, it will check the `clang-format-fallback-style`. If that is set to `"none"`, no changes will be made.

If that is not want you want, you have two options:

- Provide a `.clang-format` file (*)
- Change the `clang-format-fallback-style` to `"llvm"`

(*) To generate a `.clang-format` file, you can use:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```